# old site being shown on local machine after nameservers change has propagated

Tags: dns

4 days ago I moved my site to a new server. I changed the nameservers and if I look at the dns propagation checker tool the correct new NS records are showing, and have been for several days.

If I look on my mobile, I get the new site, but if I look via my laptop I get the old one.

I have deleted all cache and cookies, and completed a DNS flush via the commandline. Still shows the old site.

Are users likewise going to be affected? What is stopping my machine from understanding it needs to go to the new server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a line in the vhosts file pointing that website to the old server.

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/hosts`? are you talking about a reverse proxy in a virtual host configuration?